# Geolocation is working in local but doesn't on remote server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, geolocation

I uploaded the web app that I'm working on to a remote server.
Everything is working good, except for the geolocation. I can't understand what is the problem, beacuse I didn't receive any error message.
this the HTML code where geolocation is involved.

```
<tr>
<td>Ti trovi qui: <span id="location"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" id="latitude" name="latitude">
<input type="hidden" id="longitude" name="longitude">
</form>
```

These are the scripts that I use: (i'm not very prepared with javascript and jQuery)

```
function showLocation(position) {
var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
jQuery.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'getLocation.php',
    data:'latitude='+latitude+'&longitude='+longitude,
    success:function(msg){
        if(msg){
            jQuery("#location").html(msg);
        }else{
            jQuery("#location").html('Not Available');
        }
    }
});
}

function getUserCoordinates(position){

var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
document.getElementById('latitude').value=latitude
document.getElementById('longitude').value=longitude

}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getUserCoordinates);
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);
} else { 
    jQuery('#location').html('Geolocation is not supported by this    browser.');
}
});
```

This is getLocation.php file (but I don't think it's the problem):

```
<?php

require_once 'metodi.php';

sec_session_start();

if(login_check() == true){
if(!empty($_POST['latitude']) && !empty($_POST['longitude'])){

    $_SESSION['latitude'] = $_POST['latitude'];
    $_SESSION['longitude'] = $_POST['longitude'];
    //Send request and receive json data by latitude and longitude
    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($_POST['latitude']).','.trim($_POST['longitude']).'&sensor=false';
    $json = @file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $status = $data->status;
    if($status=="OK"){
        //Get address from json data
        $location = $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
    }else{
        $location =  '';
    }
    //Print address
    echo $location;
}
} else {
    echo "Non sei autorizzato a visualizzare questa pagina. Effettua il login.";
}

?>
```

Then I grab the value of hidden inputs in another php file.

Comment: anything in the returned status field? `echo $status`

Comment: I just added these lines of code and it starts to work... I don't know why xD
    `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getUserCoordinates, geoError);

    function geoError(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
    }`



But I'd like to understand.. can you explain me??

Comment: does not make a lot of sense to me. it may just of been temporarily unavailable.

Comment: I agree xD I'm going out of mind

Comment: on a shared host IP limiting may be a factor

Answer (score 1):

If your website is running in https, you also need to change this

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=
```

to this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=
```

Answer (score 0):

`getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous. When you call it twice there is no guarantee that the first call will complete before the second one does. It also makes no sense to call it twice back to back

Also it relies on third party service to return the data

Only call it once, and pass the response values to both of your functions inside one callback

Change

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getUserCoordinates);
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);
} else {
```

To

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        getUserCoordinates(position);
        showLocation(position);
   });

} else {
```

Also check that you haven't disabled geolocation in your browser for the  the remote domain. Add some console logging to see what is and isn't running within the code

Comment: ok, thank you.. i opened the chrome console and it give me this error message: `getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See [link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins) for more details.`
So I think i found the problem...
II'll make this switch and I'll update you..